# Do my components have enough white space?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, white-space

I've been working on a project but the more I see my components, the more I think they don't have enough white space.

The two components with which I have more doubt are a dropdown and a group of checkboxes. These are the components:

DROPDOWN COMPONENT
[image: Choose one]

GROUP OF CHECKBOXES
[image]

What do you think about it and how could I improve my design? Additionally, if you have any other advice regarding the design of the components, I'd happy to hear them.

Comment: Note that the most common plural in English for person is **people**.  The plural persons is generally only used in very specific situations, mostly legal or official. It looks a bit odd to use it here.

Comment: Thanks! @BillyKerr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not enough white space in my opinion.

Take a step back from the screen and try to visualize each decision a user needs to make. Think of these actions as separate blocks in the design. Consolidate each of these actions visually into grouped blocks of UI elements.

Then, the user's attention needs to flow between this chain of UI blocks.

Consider adding a thin gray line between the blocks and double the space between the blocks, this should improve the UX.

---

Also information priority is not great: I would bold the title of the items (cake), also bold the number of items (1000). Also separate between primary and secondary text information by using color.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was pretty useful information!